# SQL will only search inside of program folder

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, ms-access

[image] this same code has worked for several other programs, however i can not get it to function with this program for some reason.  what is happening is i select a file location on my desktop to read from, but the program keeps trying to open the file from inside the program files of where i have this program saved.

```
        MessageBox.Show(PATHTEXTBOX.Text);
        string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath;
        string query = "select * from Vendors";
        OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connect);
        connect.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Load(reader);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
        connect.Close();
```

Comment: It seems obvious that the value of `filePath` is incorrect or not what you think it is and likely not that of `PATHTEXTBOX` if it is supposed to be.  supply the correct path and see if it works.   Rethink the idea of requiring the user to find and remember database locations

Comment: Check the database connection string, if it is wrong you cannot connect to the database.

Comment: The way i have it setup is the program checks a txt file for the file path, so the user only selects the file location once and clicks a button to set the file path and on program startup the file path is filled into the textbox.  @Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp

Answer (score 1):

Querying the database using the "SqlDataAdapter" object was successful. I made a case to reproduce your problem and realized the query to the database.

UI page:

[image]

Vendors table data:

[image]

Test Results:

[image]

Code logic:

Query the database by clicking the test button.

Bind the DataGridView control by using code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connStr = @"Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectModels;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
        //Create an instance of SqlConnection
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        try
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            //open database
            conn.Open();
            string sql = "select * from Vendors";
            //Create an object of the SqlDataAdapter class
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            //Create an object of the DataSet class
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            //Use the SqlDataAdapter object sda to fill the new lookup results into the DataSet object ds
            sda.Fill(ds);
            //Set the DataSource property of the table control
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred!" + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                //Close the database connection
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It may be helpful to check your database connection string. Hope that helps you.